# Thermal camera interface - evocortex callback function issue

Tags: c++, camera, shared-libraries

I'm trying to interface an Optris thermal camera using [the evocortex shared library](http://documentation.evocortex.com/libirimager2/html/index.html) from a embedded linux (yocto based) system and also trying from a PC with ubuntu64.

I'm able to connect with the camera and record raw data using [this example](http://documentation.evocortex.com/libirimager2/html/examples_2linux_2minimal_2serializeRaw_8cpp-example.html), the recorded data is in a custom format in order to be openned by the Optris application (Optris PIX connect) all of this seems to be working as expected.

What I need is to get the raw thermal data and save it in our custom format (with different header), also be able to do some processing with the data. Following the documentation the way to do that is to use a callback function ([onThermalFrame](http://documentation.evocortex.com/libirimager2/html/classevo_1_1IRImagerClient.html#a47eb8ccc65f9dc999d83df6e2eecc61f)) which theoretically will make available the data for the user as unsigned short type instead char. (All of that explained in the "Temperature data format" section of the documentation).

So in order to do a quick test and see if I can get some thermal data within the callback function I modified the example code and add the callback:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <signal.h>
// Optris device interfaces
#include "IRDevice.h"
// Optris imager interfaces
#include "IRImager.h"
// Optris logging interface
#include "IRLogger.h"
// Optris raw image file writer
#include "IRFileWriter.h"


// Helper class for checking calibration files
#include "IRCalibrationManager.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace evo;
bool _keepCapturing = true;
void sigHandler(int dummy=0)
{
    _keepCapturing = false;
}

void onThermalFrame(unsigned short* thermal, unsigned int w, unsigned int h, IRFrameMetadata meta, void* arg);

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{

  signal(SIGINT, sigHandler);
  IRLogger::setVerbosity(IRLOG_DEBUG, IRLOG_DEBUG);
  const char *CONFIG_FILE = "/usr/share/libirimager/cali/generic.xml";
  IRDeviceParams params;
  IRDeviceParamsReader::readXML(CONFIG_FILE, params);
  IRDevice* dev = NULL;
  dev = IRDevice::IRCreateDevice(params);

  if(dev)
  {
    IRImager imager;
    imager.setThermalFrameCallback(onThermalFrame);
    if(imager.init(&params, dev->getFrequency(), dev->getWidth(), dev->getHeight(), dev->controlledViaHID()))
    {
      if(imager.getWidth()!=0 && imager.getHeight()!=0)
      {
        cout << "Thermal channel: " << imager.getWidth() << "x" << imager.getHeight() << "@" << imager.getMaxFramerate() << "Hz" << endl;
        // Start UVC streaming
        if(dev->startStreaming()==0)
        {
          // Enter loop in order to pass raw data to Optris image processing library.
          // Processed data are supported by the frame callback function.
          double timestamp;
          unsigned char* bufferRaw = new unsigned char[dev->getRawBufferSize()];
          char nmea[GPSBUFFERSIZE];
          memset(nmea, 0, GPSBUFFERSIZE*sizeof(*nmea));
         cout << "Decimal places: " << imager.getTemprangeDecimal() << endl;
          int serializedImages = 0;
          int chunk = 1;

          while(_keepCapturing)
          {
            if(dev->getFrame(bufferRaw, &timestamp)==IRIMAGER_SUCCESS)
            {
              imager.process(bufferRaw, NULL);
            }
          }
          delete [] bufferRaw;
        }
        else
        {
          cout << "Error occurred in starting stream ... aborting. You may need to reconnect the camera." << endl;
        }
      }
    }
    else
    {
      cout << "Error: Image streams not available or wrongly configured. Check connection of camera and config file." << endl;
    }
    delete dev;
  }
  return 0;
}

void onThermalFrame(unsigned short* thermal, unsigned int w, unsigned int h, IRFrameMetadata meta, void* arg)
{

    for (unsigned int i=0; i<h; i++)
    {
        for (unsigned int j=0; j<w; j++)
        {
            cout << thermal[i*w+j] << endl;

        }
    }
}
```

The callback function works and I can see that it is being executed for every frame.

The problem is that the data which is read are only the minimum and maximum values and all the rest temperatures values are 0.

I modified the callback in order to print only the min. and max. values and they are wrong because they are going from -41.1°C to 125.1°C and the camera is pointing to a normal room temperature (~25°C).
This is the callback mod.:

```
void onThermalFrame(unsigned short* thermal, unsigned int w, unsigned int h, IRFrameMetadata meta, void* arg)
{
  unsigned short min = 64000;
  unsigned short max = 0;
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<h; i++)
    {
        for (unsigned int j=0; j<w; j++)
        {
            //cout << thermal[i*w+j] << endl;

      if(min > thermal[i*w+j])
        min = thermal[i*w+j];
      if(max < thermal[i*w+j])
        max = thermal[i*w+j];

        }
    }
  float tMin = (float)min / 10.f - 100.f;
  float tMax = (float)max / 10.f - 100.f;
  std::cout << "min: " << tMin << " max: " << tMax << std::endl;
}
```

So as a summary, in the same code I can see 'correct' raw data before the callback (bufferRaw array) (I've just printed some values to check):

```
      while(_keepCapturing)
      {
        if(dev->getFrame(bufferRaw, &timestamp)==IRIMAGER_SUCCESS)
        {
          imager.process(bufferRaw, NULL);
        }
      }
```

But in the callback function I only get a wrong min a max values and rest of the data is 0.

**The question:**
I know it could be a bit challenging to get an answer to this because I'm dealing with a non-opensource library and I can't review/check their code (also the support is not being responsive), but does anyone have an idea what could it be happening here?

Any ideas/clues would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: the posted code looks like C++.  Please correct the question `tag` from 'c' to 'c++'

Comment: OT: regarding: `bool _keepCapturing = true;`  in general, leading underscores are 'reserved' for the C environment.  Please do not use them in user code.

Comment: OT: regarding: `signal(SIGINT, sigHandler);`  In general, in linux, the function: `signal()` is not reliable nor consistent.  Suggest using: `sigaction()`

Comment: @user3629249 thanks for the heads up about the tag (already changed), I tried suggestions and still not working... I've got the feeling that this could be more a memory issue not sure if when I'm trying to read the writer might be trying to access to the same memory, not sure how can I debug this though

Comment: if there is a problem with a reader and a writer accessing the data at the same time,  Suggest using a mutex.  The general sequence is:  When ready to access the data, set the mutex. (it will block until the data is available)  When done accessing the data, unset the mutex.

Comment: @user3629249 thanks again for the suggestion, I tried it and still not working, the problem is that the writer process is happening internally in the library so is difficult to manage a proper handshake...